# Magento 2.3.2 blank page after cache:clean

Tags: magento2, cache

I ran the command 'php bin/magento cache:clean', after this my website frontend showing a blank page. How can I debug this?

Comment: try to run all command and check

Answer (score 0):

check `var/log/system` and `var/log/debug` and `var/log/exceptions`.

run the below command:

```
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Comment: I can see in var/log/system: main.WARNING: Broken reference: The element with the "footer-toolbar-bottom" ID wasn't found. Verify the ID and try again. [] []
I haven't made any modifications.. The website is online in production mode from around 6 months...
The command setup:di:compile return me an error on step 5/7:
Class Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender does not exist
But the class exists

Comment: see the below link https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Class-Magento-Sales-Model-Resource-Order-Collection-does-not/m-p/59742#M1877

Comment: The 'Resource' word is not used here...